# PHP files in htdocs folder not wroking

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I have a php file named "test.php" in htdocs folder, when I open a browser and type "localhost/test.php" and press enter, Google Chrome telling me "This webpage is not available", and Firefox telling me "Unable to connect".

But when I type "localhost" and press enter, it opens the default html file that named "index.html" and located in htdocs folder that says "It works!" which means that Apache is running correctly.

What is the problem please?

[SOLVED]
Thanks all, problem solved when I installed Appserve now. the problem was because I installed Apache & PHP each separately, and make some changes in httpd.conf file.

Comment: Rename the index.html file to index.php and see if it still loads.

Comment: Have a look into your webservers `error.log`.

Comment: you must have made a typo somewhere! Make sure the file permissions is ok

Comment: Confirm for sure that you're using the correct htdocs folder. I had a similar problem a long time ago where it turned out that the computer I was on had multiple LAMP stacks running, and I was in the wrong one. Try creating a test.html and see if that loads.

Comment: Renamed to index.php and loaded successfully.

Comment: Tried also test.html and same problem (not load)